# When we add custom form field in Shipping Address form in Magento2 checkout page,it doesnot reflect in frontend

Tags: magento2, checkout, forms

I am using Magento 2.2.3.

I tried "[How to add new Shipping address form field in Checkout Page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html)".Below is my code.

**Vendor/Theme/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Atlantis_Everest',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Vendor/Theme/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="rewrite-checkout-fields" xsi:type="object">Atlantis\Everest\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Theme/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_field" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Theme/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Atlantis_Everest" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**Vendor/Theme/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php**

```
<?php
$customAttributeCode = 'custom_field';
$customField = [
    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'config' => [
        // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
        'customEntry' => null,
        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
        'tooltip' => [
            'description' => 'this is what the field is for',
        ],
    ],
    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
    'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
    'sortOrder' => 0,
    'validation' => [
       'required-entry' => true
    ],
    'options' => [],
    'filterBy' => null,
    'customEntry' => null,
    'visible' => true,
];

$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;
```

**Vendor/Theme/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Atlantis_Everest/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Vendor/Theme/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js**

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {

        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }

            shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['custom_field'] = shippingAddress.customAttributes['custom_field'];
            // pass execution to original action ('Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information')
            return originalAction();
        });
    };
});
```

I did not know how to perform Step 5 mentioned in the link.I performed till Step4. But When I deployed it,it does not show in Frontend. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-custom-field-in-address-form-in-magento-2/ try this @vishali Mariappan

Comment: https://navnitviradiya.com/magento-2-add-custom-field-to-shipping-address-form-in-checkout-page/

Answer (score 0):

try Clearing your static files and flushing your cache

you can do this through the backend or run

```
rm -rf pub/static && php-7.0 bin/magento cache:clean && php-7.0 bin/magento cache:flush
```

from your www/http folder from ssh

Comment: I have performed,sudo php magento setup:upgrade,sudo php magento setup:di:compile,sudo php magento setup:static-content:deploy –f,sudo php magento cache:flush,sudo chmod -R 777 var,sudo chmod -R 777 generated

Comment: you shouldnt be running chmod -R 777 on all files. this is a major security risk. 777 gives all files Read, Write and Execute permissions and should not be set up this way at all. please revise what you are doing. If your code to add a new field is not working after doing what i said, then there is an issue in your code somewhere that needs rectifying

Comment: It asked permission.So that only I run chmod for var and generated folders

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow below code to create customer address attribute for admin/frontend

1) create UpgradeData.php file(app/code/Vendor/CustomerAddressAttribute/Setup) in your existing module or create new module take reference from [here](https://github.com/hitesh-srtpl/magento226-default/tree/master/app/code/Srtpl/InstallSchemaTable)

2) paste below code in your UpgradeData.php

```
namespace Vendor\CustomerAddressAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeSetInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetInterfaceFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory  = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet     = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'district', [
            'type'             => 'varchar',
            'label'            => 'District',
            'input'            => 'text',
            'required'         => false,
            'visible'          => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'user_defined'     => false,
            'sort_order'       => 43,
            'position'         => 43,
            'system'           => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'district')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id'   => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms'      => ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address', 'customer_address'],
            ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

3) run this command **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

4) go to admin side customer -> review any customer's address tab, you will see **District** field there, also you will see at checkout -> shipping address

Comment: Thank you @Hit's.But i need to store as attribute in Database.How can I achieve that?

Comment: @VishaliMariappan see my updated answer, let me know if you have any query

Comment: Okay.i will try this and inform you.Thank you for helping me

Comment: When I added this UpgradeData.php,I faced the following errors.[ReflectionException]                                                       
  Class SR\CheckoutAdditionalField\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory does not exist  
                                                                           [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Source class "\SR\CheckoutAdditionalField\Setup\CustomerSetup" for "SR\Chec  
  koutAdditionalField\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory" generation does not exist.

Comment: SR\CheckoutAdditionalField module is I think your custom module and when you run deploy command magento unable to find SR\CheckoutAdditionalField\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory class in your module. paste your effort in your question

Comment: Actually i got this error when i run "sudo php magento setup:di:compile" command.When I deployed,I didn't get any error.When I visited the checkout page,the field is present.But under customers in admin,where should I search?Can you please give the path clearly.

Comment: Go to Customer -> All Customer -> Go inside any customer -> Addresses Tab (left side) -> Click to Add new address (you will find **District** field here)

Comment: I am sorry.Under address,I didn't find district field.What to do?Please help me@Hit's

Comment: @Hit's..Can you please help me to display custom filed value in Admin(Sales->Order->Any order view button->Under Shipping Address)?

Comment: This seems to add the new field to the customer address, which is unfortunately not the same as the billing & shipping address. The first is stored in the `customer_address` tables and the latter two are stored in the `quote_address` & `sales_order_address` tables.